# Can we extend the Rep points out to visualize their true value?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Earlier this evening I had a post answered by a prominent member of the SE community. Despite it being a meta.drupal question, I think it applies to all of the SE community out there.

This person had more than 30,000 points attributed to their profile. Yet, when I saw how it was represented XXk, I thought how unfair that was.

In the US military commissioned officers are given visual badges of their achievements:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_%28United_States%29

Can we do something similar here? Why does a person with 9000 get to be shown as longer than someone with 40000? 9000 and 40k and visually unequal.

If you had 100k points, would you want it simply represented as 100k? or 100,000? Let's give credit where credit is due. Let's give these guys rep point values they can be proud of, especially when compared against their lower ranking officers!

Although the post is a bit tongue in cheek and playful, there is, I hope, some value here. Let's create a badge system that, without having to second-glance at it immediately gives credit to those who have sacrificed more time than others for the benefit of the community.

Comment: Just as an FYI in case you didn't know - votes work differently on meta sites, so the fact you have a down vote doesn't mean it's a bad question - just that someone disagrees :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this will make it any better than worse (wondering what clive and other multi-thousand reputed users would say).

These units are made to avoid what you are trying to get back.

8 GB is, in my opinion looks decent than 8192 MB.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of what badges are for.

Comment: The OP is asking to always show all the digits of the reputation. Reputation and badges are two different things, as most badges are not directly linked to the reputation. For example, [ermannob](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/11884/ermannob) has 11 bronze badges, but his reputation is 354; [David Thomas](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7153/david-thomas) has 8 bronze badges, but his reputation is 2689, and he is the user who gained more reputation this year.

Answer (score 0):

Once you become a 10K user, it doesn't matter so much if the user's reputation is shown as 34,492 or 34.5K. The reputation is written using all the digits in the user profile page (in my case, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno).